# How to change the styling of nested child element inside a shadow DOM using angular

Tags: html, css, angular, css-selectors, shadow-dom

I want to change the font style of a child element which is wrapped inside a parent element which is internally wrapped by others and finally it is enclosed inside a shadow root. Attaching the DOM tree structure -

[DOM structure description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xTFD.png)

I tried making changes by following code

```
let host = document.querySelector(".fs-timescale-dd");
      // host.setAttribute('style','font-style:normal');
       let child= host.querySelector('.select');
       child.querySelector('.ng-select').querySelector('.ng-select-container')
       .querySelector('ng-value-container').querySelector('ng-placeholder')
       .setAttribute('style','font-style:normal');
```

But I'm getting TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'querySelector')

I'm new to Angular, can someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have not clearly mentioned your goal. After reading your question what I can understand is you want to change the font style of the options of the dropdown. If so you can do this from the following example. You can directly select the class on which you want to apply the style.

```
::ng-deep .some-class {
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the approach. But this is not working. I have attached the DOM structure for reference. Only accessible element is eds-select but font-style property is defined inside shadow-root and has to be changed

Answer (score 0):

Solved by referencing the shadow dom element by adding a class name to it.
Something like this -

```js
document.querySelector(".fs-timescale-dd").className('someName').shadowRoot.setAttribute("font","arial")
```